# Should I build a wrapper around this entity?

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following layout:

Entities:

```
Order
OrderItem
```

DAO classes:

```
OrderDAO
OrderItemDAO
```

So I have POCO classes, and DAO classes.

Now I want to encapsulate the above entities into another entity, so I can have methods like:

```
x.AddItem(OrderItem item)
x.CalculateTotal();
x.CalculateShipping();
x.Charge();
```

What would this type of entity be called? Factory? Or just a simple wrapper class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, I divide my code base into several layers: Modeling layer, Data Access layer, Manager/business-logic layer, and UI

In this case, I'd suggest leaving Order/OrderItem POCOs and creating an OrderManager class. It would be a stateless singleton, and have methods like AddItem(Order, OrderItem). Internally, it would deal with the specifics of updating the models, committing data changes, any transactionality, etc.

Comment: I like the solution. Elegant enough. Though, there is a bit of wondering whether it creates (too) strong coupling between the "manager" class and the DAO layer.

Comment: The DAO layer handles loads/queries/commits and could be handed to the manager during construction by interface (In Java land I use Guice for this kind of injection). I've found that if you've gone at least that far (dependency injection) you don't need to worry about abstracting the interfaces until you really need to, because the abstraction lines are well understood.

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely not be a factory (that could be the object that *creates* your "joint" entity, though). Possibly a wrapper, yes. But why not have the `Order` entity manage its `OrderItem`s directly by creating a relationship between both?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a Facade Pattern to me. Hide the actual implementation of the act of doing those various processes. Or in layman terms a wrapper would be correct.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern